# How to get all images on website, even if they are not currently displayed using javascript

Tags: javascript, whatsapp

I know how to get all images from a website using javascript, e.g.:

```
var images = document.getElementsByTagName('img'); 
var srcList = [];
for(var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
    srcList.push(images[i].src);
}
```

However, when using a website like web.whatsapp.com this function will only provide images from the chat that is currently active. I wonder if it is possible to get the images from the other chats as well (assuming that they are already loaded), even if they are not the active chat displayed at the moment. Or alternativeley, if there is a way to make a certain chat as active using javascript.

Comment: there very well might not be an JS-reachable handles to those hidden images, either from being private variables or from being not loaded until the html of the message is displayed.

Comment: would it be possible using chromedriver or geckodriver?

Comment: i would go to tampermonkey first, it can do anything you can, including "clicking" through all the conversations to invoke the image loading. but yeah, those kind of things will work.